# When was the 50 billionth human born?

Tags: prehistory, anthropology, world, population

I don't know if this question belongs precisely at History.SE, but I can't think of a more fitting alternative.

I've heard the estimate several times that about 100 billion humans have existed throughout human history. (I guess this depends somewhat arbitrarily on when you start counting our ancestors as human, but let's say we've settled on a fixed beginning moment and work with that for the rest of this question.)

When had half of all humans who have ever existed (until today) been born already? If the 100 billion number is correct, then I'm asking when the 50 billionth person was born.

Note that whatever the answer is, we can say that most of the humans who have ever existed were born after that date (or since slightly before that date).

Comment: 'somewhat'? I think we need a better definition. Ignoring the morality of the situation, perhaps it's the earliest proto-human with which a modern human could successfully mate?

Comment: The last paragraph seems contradictory. "most humans were born after that date" Wouldn't it be the case that **half** were born after that date and half before that date? In fact, 50 billion would have been born before that date and 50 billion after.

Comment: @Loduwijk Hence the "or since slightly before that date." It only takes half + 1 person to become "most."

Comment: I know that the results returned by Google vary by geographic location etc., but the page cited in the answer below comes up as the 3rd result on the first page when I copy/paste your question into Google.  Per our [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this site is not about "_Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page_".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Data published by the demographer [Carl Haub](https://e360.yale.edu/authors/carl-haub) and [Dr. Toshiko Kaneda](https://www.prb.org/people/toshiko-kaneda/) in [*How Many People Have Ever Lived on Earth?*](https://www.prb.org/howmanypeoplehaveeverlivedonearth/) on the Population Reference Bureau (PRB) website suggests that **the 50 billionth person would have been born around 130 AD / CE**. This can be seen by looking at the column 'Number Ever Born' in the table below:

[image]

*Image source: [Population Reference Bureau (PRB)](https://www.prb.org/howmanypeoplehaveeverlivedonearth/). Table data sources: Toshiko Kaneda and Genevieve Dupuis, '2017 World Population Data Sheet' (Washington, DC: Population Reference Bureau, 2017); United Nations Population Division, 'World Population Prospects: The 2017 Revision' (New York: United Nations, 2017).*

In 130 AD:

- [Hadrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian) was emperor of Rome.
- The [Han dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty) ruled in China.
- The [Kushan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushan_Empire) was around 100 years old and had about another 245
  years to go.
- [Claudius Ptolemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy), Greek mathematician, astronomer, geographer
  and astrologer, was probably in his 30s.
- [Galen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen), Greek physician, surgeon and philosopher, was an infant
  and would have been close to being the 50 billionth person born.

Carl Haub originally made these calculations in 1995 to [dispel the myth that](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/do-living-people-outnumber-the-dead/)

> The human population has swelled so much that people alive today
>   outnumber all those who have ever lived

*(His data estimates showed that "those alive in 2002 constituted only about 6 percent", far from the 'myth' of more than half.)*

He and Toshiko Kaneda updated the data in 2002 and 2011, conceding that their approach is (of necessity) "semi-scientific". On the methods used in their calculations, [the authors say that](https://www.prb.org/howmanypeoplehaveeverlivedonearth/)

> calculating the number of people who have ever lived is part science
>   and part art. No demographic data exist for 99 percent of the span of
>   human existence. Still, with some assumptions about prehistoric
>   populations, we can get a rough idea of this historic number...

They take [50,000 BC as the starting date](https://www.prb.org/howmanypeoplehaveeverlivedonearth/):

> Fixing a time when the human race actually came into existence is not
>   straightforward. Hominids walked the Earth as early as several million
>   years ago, and various ancestors of Homo sapiens appeared at least as
>   early as 700,000 B.C. According to the United Nations Determinants and
>   Consequences of Population Trends, modern Homo sapiens may have
>   appeared about 50,000 B.C.

This corresponds "[to the start of the Upper Paleolithic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens)" and "the emergence of full behavioral modernity" ("[behavioral and cognitive traits that distinguishes current Homo sapiens from other anatomically modern humans, hominins, and primates.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_modernity)").

The articles *[How Many People Have Ever Lived on Earth?](https://www.prb.org/howmanypeoplehaveeverlivedonearth/)* and [Do Living People Outnumber the Dead?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/do-living-people-outnumber-the-dead/) go into details on how the estimates were arrived at (the details are a bit lengthy to include here...).

The margin of error for the birth of the 50 billionth person who ever lived is fairly large; Hadrian may not have been born or Galen may have been dead and buried rather than an infant, but the Kushan empire and the Han dynasty cover considerably longer time periods.

Comment: Great find! I thought we were going to be reduced to doing our own calculus. :-P

Comment: Interesting - when did they start counting? (Since evolution is so gradual)

Comment: Do they start 8000BC/10000BP, ignoring >99% of human evolution ? Even the time frame for anatomically modern humans (50,000BP) is wrong on that site, earliest traits appear between 200,000 and 300,000 (Jebel Irhoud being the oldest for now). It can be doubted that a serious answer is possible at all, or only under very limting assumptions, which makes the number ... cute. :-)

Comment: @ebv See updated answer. Yes, 'cute' is one way of putting it :). The authors readily concede that assumptions have been made, and they have not started with *anatomically modern humans* but rather *behavioral modernity*.

Comment: @Lars Bosteen: Ok :-) All is debatable, and i do not have a better answer, only hair-splitting. One day we'll discuss the paleaolithic and behavioural modernity ;-)

Comment: Concerning the myth `The human population has swelled so much that people alive today outnumber all those who have ever lived`, could it have ever happened?

Comment: @baudsp: Depends on your assumptions - and thus when you start counting. As T.E.D.'s deleted answer shows, the sheer length of the left-side tail is hard to comprehend, and has much more area than seems intuitively possible.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks

Comment: @baudsp technically, this holds true for part of the lifespan of the first human counted. Child mortality makes it unlikely that it was ever true for more than, say, 40 years? The cutoff is quite arbitrary. It could be interesting to see something like "how far back do you have to go, until the number of persons having died since then exceeds the current population".

Comment: @LarsBosteen if this is the chosen definition, the choice of "2" as the earliest population seems incorrect and misleading. If you can isolate a population of exactly two who are "behaviorally modern" then before the younger of them was born the population was 1. And the choice of "2" somewhat implies that all other behaviorally modern humans are descended from one behaviorally modern human couple, which I'm sure is quite far from prevailing ideas in natural history research.

Comment: Imo, there is no "correct" reproducible apporach to calculate a human population on earth at any given time, or in a given geography. We can't tell from the findings what species or sub-species left them behind, this only works in Europe before 50,000BP and after 20,000BP. We can assume that the date is rather older, at least not younger than what has been said.

Comment: @Chieron If the first two humans had more than two kids, and several died, the dead could outnumber the living even during the first humans' lives.  Imagine the first two parents have 7 children, 5 of whom die in infancy.  You now have 4 living, 5 dead, even in the first generation.

Comment: Any line is going to be arbitrary.  You can trace ancestry all the way back to single-cell organisms and you will never find a generation that appears substantially different from the immediately previous one.

Comment: It's also very important that over half of people who were born before 1900 died within a year of birth, and therefore had little impact on the size of the population.

Comment: We definitely need citations for that one, best if they differentiate between population types and times and are based on available data.